# ReactJS not call method from Smart Contract (NEAR) on product (testnet does not exist while viewing)

Tags: reactjs, smartcontracts, nearprotocol, assemblyscript, near

I deployed successfully my first app (AssemblyScript + Reactjs), but when i test on github-pages, i got this error.

```
errors.js:18 Uncaught (in promise) Error: [-32000] Server error: account xxx.testnet does not exist while viewing
at json-rpc-provider.js:322
at async Object.e [as default] (exponential-backoff.js:7)
at async y.sendJsonRpc (json-rpc-provider.js:297)
at async y.query (json-rpc-provider.js:109)
at async _.viewFunction (account.js:366)
```

I test method contract with near-cli and it's ok, so i don't understand why web not work. Thanks you all.

[testnet does not exist while viewing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcs2p.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy contract to testnet server (accountId be like xxx.testnet), you should remove `process.env.NODE_ENV` at `src/utils.js`:

> const nearConfig = getConfig("development");

because When you run `npm start`, `process.env.NODE_ENV` is always equal to 'development', when you run `npm test` it is always equal to 'test', and when you run `npm run build` to make a production bundle, it is always equal to 'production'. So if `nearConfig` is production config, all url are mainnet server, not testnet server that you deployed your contract!